# Can't connect to specific website using URLConnection, Read timed out

Tags: java, web-scraping

I am using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String EngLink;
    URL EngUrl;
    URLConnection EngCon;
    String cookiesHeader;
    InputStream EngIs;
    BufferedReader EngBr;
    String line;
    String EngPageHtml="";

    EngLink="https://www.zomato.com/";
    EngUrl = new URL(EngLink);
    EngCon = (HttpURLConnection) EngUrl.openConnection();
    EngCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");

    EngIs = EngCon.getInputStream();
    EngBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(EngIs,"UTF-8"));

    while ((line = EngBr.readLine()) != null) {
        EngPageHtml = EngPageHtml + "\n" + line;
    }

    System.out.println(EngPageHtml);        
    }
```

and what I am trying to do is get the raw html of the site.
However, when I run the code I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at project1.Aaa.main(Aaa.java:33)
```

I am using this code to succesfully get HTML of multiple other sites, but this particular one does not work.

What could be the problem and how can I go around this?

EDIT: Loading the site in firefox, getting the cookie from there and passing it in :

```
EngCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
```

makes the page load, but this is not good as it cant be used over and over again.

Comment: Have you tried this url https://www.zomato.com/mumbai ?

Comment: You need to use "HttpsURLConnection" not the "HttpURLConnection" and need to import "javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection".

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga `HttpsURLConnection` is a subclass of `HttpURLConnection`, so if you don't need access to any SSL features, using `HttpURLConnection` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Seeting the cookie from the one I get in mozzilla worked, specifically the two values for "ak_bmsc" and "bm_sv". Others are PHPSESSID=null; fbcity=93; zl=en; fbtrack=null; dpr=2; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; csrf=null;

using this makes the page load, however I would obviously prefer method that does not need me to copy the cookie from mozilla, because I have no idea how long will that work

Comment: `Read timed out` errors are usuall caused by a proxy or firewall. In case there is a firewall (from within a corporate network, for example), you must set the **networking properties** to set the proxy and optional authentication: `https.proxyHost`, `https.proxyPort`, etc.

Comment: @LittleSanti If this was the case, would it not affect all the other sites? As I mentioned this piece of codes works on other sites without any issues, it is just this one giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding another request property:

```
EngCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
```

Nothing else was needed